# Whats the best way for reactjs web app in production server

Tags: reactjs, apache, nginx, next.js

First, I planed deploy a reactjs website to production server by Apache.

But when I searched the thing in google, it showed me many way to serve a reactjs web app

For example:

Pm2, or just simple by using next start (i'm using nextjs)

So, is Pm2 or next start is good enough for production server.
or the traditional web http server (apache, nginx)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personnally, I use a simple apache server which deserve react like this

```
DocumentRoot /www
<Directory "/www">
    RewriteEngine on
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</Directory>
```